# Can't login with requests module

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I have a python bot which logs in with my account into my school website and checks the homework. Just yesterday they updated something, and now I can't login...

My code looks like this:

```py
    session_requests = requests.session()
    result = session_requests.get("https://dienynas.tamo.lt/Prisijungimas/Login")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'lxml')
    SToken = soup.find(attrs={"name": "SToken"})['value']
    authenticity_token = soup.find(attrs={"name": "__RequestVerificationToken"})['value']
    payload = {
        "UserName": "<my username>",
        "Password": "<my password>",
        "IsMobileUser": "false",
        "ReturnUrl": "",
        "RequireCaptcha": "false",
        "Timestamp": datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
        "SToken": SToken
    }
    headers = {
        "cookie": "__RequestVerificationToken="+authenticity_token,
        "origin": "https://dienynas.tamo.lt",
        "referer": "https://dienynas.tamo.lt/Prisijungimas/Login",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
        }
    result = session_requests.post("https://dienynas.tamo.lt/", params = payload, headers = headers)
```

And the responses I get are the same as if I just sent a simple `GET` request to that page. I have spent many hours on this and still can't figure out what's wrong. Please help!

The website - https://dienynas.tamo.lt

It looks like I send all the data that gets sent when I log-in with my browser, but it doesn't work...

Also, I don't know if this information is important, but before the update, I could login with only this form data - `UserName`, `Password`, `IsMobileUser`, `ReturnUrl` and `__RequestVerificationToken` (which is now sent in the `cookie` header for some reason)

Comment: Try using the `"Timestamp"` from the `<form` instead of get new one from `datetime`. I assume the `Timestamp` is related to the `SToken`.

Comment: @stovfl thanks. I already figured it out. But still, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I am dumb. For some reason I was using my own time for the `Timestamp`, instead of just scraping it together with `SToken`. Then, they do not match and the server does not log me in...
Working code:

```py
    session_requests = requests.session()
    result = session_requests.get("https://dienynas.tamo.lt/Prisijungimas/Login")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'lxml')
    SToken = soup.find(attrs={"name": "SToken"})['value']
    timestamp = soup.find(attrs={"name": "Timestamp"})['value']
    payload = {
        'UserName': '<myUsername>',
        'Password': '<MyPassword>',
        'IsMobileUser': 'false',
        'ReturnUrl': '',
        'RequireCaptcha': 'false',
        'Timestamp': timestamp,
        'SToken': SToken
    }
    r = session_requests.post("https://dienynas.tamo.lt/", data = payload)
```